# Exclude `unknown[]` from a union with a tuple?

Tags: typescript

I don't *think* this is possible, but I wanted to ask here before raising an issue on github.

I have a type that looks like this:

```js
type X = [string, number] | unknown[]
```

I want to extract the `[string, number]` part. Is this possible? This doesn't work:

```js
type Y = Exclude<X, unknown[]>
```

With the above, `Y` is `never`. I understand why, because `[string, number]` extends `unknown[]`, so by excluding it both sides of the union are "rejected". But are there any clever conditional types that can be used to get rid of `unknown[]`?

Note: I am not defining `X` myself, I'm trying to write a function signature where one of the intermediate types *looks like* `[string, number] | unknown[]`. So I can't just use `[string, number]` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From examples in [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type)

> In an intersection everything absorbs unknown

We can create type that is for sure has nothing common with real types, e.g:

```
type Noop = { __noop: '__noop' };
```

Then in conditional type we can check if intersection of array item extends our fake type and if yes - exclude it (as we know it must be `unknown`):

```
type ExcludeUnknown<T> = T extends Array<infer I>
  ? Noop extends (I & Noop) ? never : T
  : T;

type Y = ExcludeUnknown<X>; // [string, number]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDaBnYAnAlgOwOYBopsBXAWwCMJ0BdKAHymOwGtsB7Ad2yWoG4AofqEhQAcmzZgEUAN5QA%20vPaSAXFADki5WHVQAvgKHhoAUQAeAYwA2xACYQAqi3ZcAPABUAfNPdQIZ4AhsWxQoAEF0dABDEFccADMqKABJT34oKAB%20MQkpf0Dg0IAKZKgAMhzJAEosoggANyS1d3SoZsNhaABNaXNrO0dnTmxXGE9eKAB6SeQ0LDxCEgoqaiA)

---

** Pay attention, this won't work with tuples containing `{}`, `object` or `unknown` (e.g. `[string, number, {}]`)